# Restart by Hitting "Enter"

Tags: python, pygame

I am not sure why my code to restart my game on python (using pygame) is not working?
Following the completion of my main function (when the game is won by having no more items on the screen i.e. an empty "bears" array) I change the startGame variable to "False": 
I.e.

```
 if len(bears) == 0:
    startGame = False
```

Then after I write:

```
   #draw the window
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)


play_again()
pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
```

The play_again() function is my attempt at defining the "restart" button. It's code is:

```
def play_again():
    windowSurface.blit(text, (90, 104))
    windowSurface.blit(restart, (80,180))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.display.flip()
    in_main_menu = True
    while in_main_menu:
        clock.tick(50)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                in_main_menu = False
                pygame.display.quit()
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RETURN:
                    global startGame
                    startGame = True
                    in_main_menu = False
```

I'm not sure why this method is not working. (Also in case anyone is wondering, I have defined the "text" and "restart" variables earlier and they are fine)

Comment: Oh I just realized the while in_main_menu should be changed to "while in_main_menu == True" (I think?) and have made the change, but it does not make a difference in the restarting of the program

Comment: @Dunno it is not restarting the game's main function, which is defined to start when:

startGame = True

Comment: May I introduce you to [goto for Python](http://entrian.com/goto/)? :-)

Comment: `while in_main_menu` and `while in_main_menu == True` means the same.

Comment: As for me problem is outside `play_again()`.

Comment: You will have to show more code because problem is with your loop - you have `play_again()` outside of loop. `play_again()` has the same indention as `pygame.display.quit()` and `pygame.quit()` so `play_again()` is outside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

As for me you leave mainloop, call `play_again()` but you are outside loop so you can return to beggining of code.

You need another, external loop to return (after play_again()) to the beginning of code.

It could be similar to this:

```
while StartGame:

    while game:

            # game

    #StartGame = play_again()
    play_again()

pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
```

And remeber: if you have problem, add a lot `print` with some information to see what's goin on in your code - (`"I'm in loop"`, `"I leaves loop"`, `"variable StarGame is:"`, etc)

Comment: Hey everyone! I managed to fix the problem!
 if len(bears) == 0:
        play_again()

i changed the end code to that rather than:

 if len(bears) == 0:startGame = False

play_again()

This put play_again() back into the loop

Comment: As I said before - you had `play_again()` in wrong place.